# Link Button in PDF Doesn't Work

Tags: pdf, filemaker

I have a FileMaker Pro 11 layout containing a button with an action of "open URL." When the layout is saved as a PDF, the button appears but no longer works (clicking on it doesn't do anything). Is there a way to save as PDF with the PDF containing a working "open URL" button?

Thank you,
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be in browse mode for your button to work. You are probably in preview mode. Buttons don't work in preview mode (which makes sense as it is just a preview of what will be printed).

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to get a button to work in the outputted PDF. Using full Acrobat, I can create working link buttons in PDFs. I'm wondering how to do this in FMP/if it is possible.

Comment: PDF does not (and probably never will) recognize FileMaker script steps. I think you will need to edit your PDF using PDF editing software.